# how to write javascript file in Netbeans IDE 6.7.1

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans6.7

i am new to Netbeans, i created the web project, 
now i want to write javascript for one html page, 
how should i write,

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to create a .js file: File -> New File... -> Other -> JavaScript File

Else just add `<script type="text/javascript">...</script>` to head of your HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

in the head of your html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //your javascript code
    alert('Hello js');
</script>
```

Comment: hi,
i want to write external script file,
how should i write.